# Cmake giving an error saying that Qt 5.14.2 is not usable

Tags: qt, cmake, geant4

[image: cmake error]

Here is the error that I am receiving from cmake. It is able to find qt5 but it is deeming it unusable. Any suggestions to fix this?

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1314 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "5.14.2" from
  /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.2/bin/qmake, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4InterfaceOptions.cmake:120 (find_package)
  cmake/Modules/G4CMakeMain.cmake:64 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (include)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error message into the question post.

Comment: The error message `"this code requires Qt 4.x"` seems to be suggesting that the build requires Qt4.  (For future reference error messages etc. should be included in the question as text *not* images.)

Comment: It does seem to suggest that, however, when I look at the Geant4InterfaceOptions.cmake file it appears to say that it will search for Qt5 first and then qt4 if qt5 is not found.

Comment: If you expect that QT5 installation should be found, you may replace `find_package(Qt5Core QUIET)` line with `find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)` and look into resulted error message. (This is just for debugging purposes. I agree that finding QT5 via `FindQT4.cmake` script but not finding it via `FindQT5.cmake` looks strange.)

Comment: Can you provide us the command line you are using to configure Geant4 with CMake? You might need to add `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.2` to the CMake command line to make `find_package` command use `CONFIG` mode rather than `MODULE` mode.

Comment: @Tsyvarev unfortunately there is no `FindQt5.cmake` module in the default CMake distribution. So your best choice is to use the CONFIG mode.